# How to get bitlocker recovery keys for Intune device with MS Graph

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, bitlocker, microsoft-graph-intune

I am trying to get a list of all devices from Intune and their associated bitlocker keys, if there is one. I am able to get a list of all devices no problem, but I can not find the correct permissions to get the bitlocker keys. I am using Powershell for 2 methods: one using the Graph cmdlets provided by Microsoft, and another using the API and `Invoke-RestMethod`. Both methods are using the same service principal for authentication.

Method 1:

```
C:\> Get-MgInformationProtectionBitlockerRecoveryKey
Get-MgInformationProtectionBitlockerRecoveryKey_List1: Failed to authorize, token doesn't have the required permissions.
```

Method 2:

```
C:\> $Params = @{
>>     Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/informationProtection/bitlocker/recoveryKeys"
>>     Headers = @{
>>         Authorization = "Bearer $Token"
>>         ConsistencyLevel = "eventual"
>>     }
>>     ErrorAction = 'Stop'
>> }
C:\> (Invoke-RestMethod @Params)
Invoke-RestMethod: {"error":{"code":"authorization_error","message":"Failed to authorize, token 
doesn't have the required permissions.","innerError":{"date":"2023-11-10T19:18:31",
"request-id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","client-request-id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}}
```

The service principal we are using has always worked in the past. The service principal was granted both the Global Reader and Intune Administrator roles, as well as the `BitlockerKey.Read.All` app permission. Note that the `BitlockerKey.Read.All` had to be set to Delegated, as no Application permissions were available. I have been following the instructions from [this documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bitlocker-list-recoverykeys?view=graph-rest-1.0) saying that it has to be set to Delegated but you must grant certain role access, however I am still unable to get authorization.

Does anybody know how to properly authenticate, or know of a way to get the bitlocker keys?

Edit: I am providing the Powershell used to authenticate for both methods.

Method 1: `Connect-MgGraph`

The `$ClientId` is the id of the service principal, found in Entra > Identity > Applications > App Registrations. The `$ClientSecret` is password.

```
$Params = @{
    ClientId = $ClientId
    ClientSecret = $ClientSecret
    TenantId = $TenantId
    ForceRefresh = $true
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
}
$AccessToken = (Get-MsalToken @Params).AccessToken
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $AccessToken -ErrorAction Stop |Out-Null
```

Method 2: `Invoke-RestMethod` with the Graph API

The `$Credential` variable is the credentials of the same service principal used in Method 1.

```
$Params = @{
    Uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    Body = @{
        'client_id' = $Credential.UserName
        'scope' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
        'client_secret' = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().password
        'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
    }
    Method = 'Post'
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
}
$GraphAccessToken = Invoke-RestMethod @Params |Select-Object -ExpandProperty access_token
[pscustomobject]@{
    GraphAccessToken = $GraphAccessToken
}
```

Edit 2: I tried the steps in the verified answer of [this Stackoverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652740/cannot-call-graph-api-using-delegated-permissions-in-powershell) about adding the additional Uri in the Authentication page in Entra, but with no luck. It still yields the exact same results. I also tried using `Get-MsalToken` instead of `Invoke-RestMethod` to get the access token. This had no impact as well.

Comment: What status code is being returned?  Good request should be 200 OK.  Did you get a new token?  Method 1 may be failing because the token expired.

Comment: Its still giving me the same error. After giving it the weekend and attempting both methods, its giving me two authorization errors. I do not know the exact error code, but the full error message is in the post above.

Comment: You are using two step authentication.  Step 1 is to get a token (cookie).  Your issue is the permission used to get the token.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#microsoft-graph-permissions

Comment: I have been using the same authentication methods for years with no issue. I edited the question and included the code used to authenticate to Graph. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Recently most systems are moving from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2 because OAUTH2 is supported on Windows, MAC, and Linux.  Has anything changed on your system?  Do you working apps still work?

Comment: Yes. I should clarify everything else is working great, but the issue is specifically with the bitlocker. The permission has to be set to Delegated instead of Application, and I believe this is causing the issue. We have tried granting the service principal various roles that are supposed to allow delegated permissions to work, but with no luck. Everything else working great.

Comment: Do web search for following : ms graph authentication troubleshoot

Comment: I've done research all afternoon for this. I followed the directions in the Edit 2 section above with no luck. I have tried multiple ways of getting the access token. I am able to get the token fine, but I always run into the same error when attempting to authorize anything for bitlocker. I can still get anything else, but its only with bitlocker that I'm running into the issue because its a delegated permission instead of application

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors

Comment: Already looked at that yesterday. I figured out my error is a 401 error, and the only 401 solution in that documentation is an invalid token. I know the token is valid because its brand new and works for anything else. Literally the only thing I cannot access is bitlocker because its set to Delegated.

Comment: Error 401 is unauthorized (not invalid).  Which means the route is not consistent with the user associated with the token.  It is a permission issue.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#delegated-access-access-on-behalf-of-a-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for those wondering. Since I was only doing a one-time export, I just ran it from my own personal account, although a service account may work just as fine. I did not use the service principal to authenticate. Here is the basic code:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'BitLockerKey.Read.All' -TenantId 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
$BitLockerKeys = Get-MgInformationProtectionBitlockerRecoveryKey -All
```